# Jenkins CLI exception: missing Job/ExtendedRead permission

Tags: permissions, jenkins, command-line-interface

I have a Jenkins user that I want to give rights to run the remote CLI towards the Jenkins instance. The first command is to fetch the config.xml:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins:8080/hudson get-job thejob
```

However when he invokes the command, it fails with:

```
Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: \
  hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: \
  USER is missing the Job/ExtendedRead permission \
  at hudson.security.ACL.checkPermission(ACL.java:54)
```

I have given the rights to execute scripts, read/create/configure jobs and more in our matrix-based security grid. There is another user who has EXACTLY the same permissions in the grid, but for this other user, everything works fine.

I don't have any of the plugins 'Extended Read permission' or 'Read-only configurations' installed.

I cannot see why it fails for this new user. Suggestions anyone?

Differences in the 2 users config.xml file:

```
<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.UserCredentialsProvider_-UserCredentialsProperty plugin="credentials@1.4">
    <credentials/>
```

vs:

```
<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.UserCredentialsProvider_-UserCredentialsProperty plugin="credentials@1.8.3">
    <domainCredentialsMap class="hudson.util.CopyOnWriteMap$Hash"/>
```

And a final one:

```
<hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>
  <passwordHash>some values...</passwordHash>
</hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>
```

Comment: You could try retrieving the xml file for both users and comparing it.

Comment: Thanks Patrice. I added the diff to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are facing the same problem I had, but take a look here:
[Jenkins CLI: using Anonymous permissions instead of the user defined ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591952/jenkins-cli-using-anonymous-permissions-instead-of-the-user-defined-ones/28603320#28603320)

Comment: Will try that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have upgraded the credentials plugin but somehow the first user didn't get its record updated.
If you can I would suggest trying to update to the latest (1.9.1 for me). You could also edit the user record manually and force the real plugin version number in there (then restart Jenkins) and see if it processes this user more accurately.

Comment: It's actually the user with the higher version credentials plugin that has all the problems :(

Comment: Can you tell(by going to Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Installed tab) what version of the plugin you have currently installed ? Is there an update ?

Comment: Also, can you try forcing the actual credential version into these xml records to see if that helps ?